# Creating a ring/circle sector with the CanvasRenderer

Tags: three.js

Trying to create a number of circle/ring segments using Three.JS and the CanvasRenderer.

Example using `THREE.Shape` and `THREE.ShapeGeometry` here: http://jsfiddle.net/25U8E/1/

The triangulation looks wrong to me and when I tried to move the vertices by directly modifying geometry.vertices[n].x etc. the THREE.Shape I am using degrades and becomes less smooth.

Is there a better way to create a sector - one that allows me to modify the vertices afterwards?

Comment: Try `THREE.RingGeometry( 150, 300, 16, 2, 0, Math.PI / 4 );` and then explain what you mean by "modify the vertices" and "less smooth".

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit vague - it was very late. This http://i.imgur.com/iI4B6yx.png compositte screen shot shows what I mean. Top sector is when the app starts and bottom one is after a couple of iterations of moving the geometry.vertices around to change the size of the sector. The code to move each vert is the same as the one to create them initially so I don't *think* it's a math error. 

Maybe that's not a valid thing to do once the mesh is created?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NWJQk/ I tried using THREE.RingGeometry. If I don't use THREE.DoubleSide for the material the segment doesn't render correctly. If I do, there is a lot of z-fighting.

Is there something else I have to set?

Comment: Yikes! That is a bug in `RingGeometry`. Look at it in wireframe mode, and you can see that the left and right edges are connected with faces. But `RingGeometry` is what you should be using -- if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the Stackoverflow-y thing to do but here goes:

The right way to create a ring sector like I need is to use the RingGeometry class like this:

`THREE.RingGeometry( 150, 300, 16, 2, 0, Math.PI / 4 );`

It does contain a bug that means some of the verts are wrong - illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/NWJQk/ - as it spins, you'll see the back side is wrong.

That fiddle references the URL for the latest version of Three.JS so if it starts working, it means the bug was fixed and released.

Edit: Clearer illustration of what's failing using wireframe: http://jsfiddle.net/NWJQk/3/